# set color for each violin in violin plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I tried `violin` plot in Seaborn with different colors for each violin as:

```
sns.violinplot(x='type', y='den', data=mydf, ax=axes[0], color=['red','blue','yellow'])
```

however I got:

> ValueError: to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "('red', 'blue', 'yellow')"
>   could not convert string to float: red

Answer (score 11):

I think you should use the `palette` keyword:

> **color** : matplotlib color, optional
>
> Color for all of the elements, or seed for light_palette() when using hue nesting.
>
> **palette** : seaborn color palette or dict, optional
>
> Colors to use for the different levels of the hue variable. Should be something that can be interpreted by color_palette(), or a dictionary mapping hue levels to matplotlib colors.

```
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random([100,4])

sb.violinplot(data=data, palette=['r','g','b','m'])
```

[image]